# How to extract words from a string that end with substrings listed in an array? BigQuery

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have a table of rows with cells containing multiple strings. Like this:

```
 K1111=V1111;K1=V1;kv13_key4=--xxxxxsomething;id5=true;impid=23123123;location=domain_co_uk
```

I need to extract a substring that begins with kv13_key4= and ends with anything after but the lengths all vary and the substrings are all separated by a semicolon ; . I tried

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(customtargeting,'%in2w_key4%;') As contains_key_Value
```

but didn't work. I need something like this:

```
| Original Cell                                                                                            | Extracted                      |
| key88=1811111;id89=9990string;K1=V1;23234234234tttttttt13_key4=--x;id5=true;impid=23123;url=domain_co_uk | kv13_key4=--x                  |
| K1111=V1111;K1=V1;kv13_key4=--xsomething;id5=true;impid=23123123;location=domain_co_uk                   | kv13_key4=--xsomething         |
| ;id5=true;T6791=V1111;K1=V1;kv13_key4=--xxxxxsomething123;impid=23123                                    | kv13_key4=--xxxxxsomething123  |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider below

```
select *, regexp_extract(customtargeting, r'kv13_key4=[^;]+') as Extracted
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Does this regex work:

```
(?<=kv13_key4=)[^;]+(?=;)
```

It captures everything between 'kv13_key4=' and the nearest ';'

Your REGEX_EXTRACT would look like:

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(customtargeting,r'(?<=kv13_key4=)[^;]+(?=;)')
```

Comment: Ah no not quite, I recieve this error: Error running query
Cannot parse regular expression: invalid perl operator: (?<

Comment: am I using the function correctly in big query :

REGEXP_EXTRACT(customtargeting,'(?<=kv13_key4=)[^;]+(?=;)')

Comment: @dweebz prefix a 'r' to the regex part like this: `REGEXP_EXTRACT(customtargeting,r'(?<=kv13_key4=)[^;]+(?=;)')`